# List of users in MVC 5 Asp.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm just starting to learn MVC. Can you explain in details how to: List all users, delete/create users and edit information about user. Now my HomeController looks like this:

```
private ApplicationSignInManager _signInManager;
private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;

public HomeController()
{
}

public HomeController(ApplicationUserManager userManager, ApplicationSignInManager signInManager)
{
    UserManager = userManager;
    SignInManager = signInManager;
}

public ApplicationSignInManager SignInManager
{
    get
    {
        return _signInManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationSignInManager>();
    }
    private set
    {
        _signInManager = value;
    }
}

public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
{
    get
    {
        return _userManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
    }
    private set
    {
        _userManager = value;
    }
}

public ActionResult Index()
{
    var us = UserManager.Users.ToList();
    return View(us);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Start from the beginning**: read a detailed tutorial about how to write some basic CRUD application.

[Start from here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application). Once completed, go to the [next one](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-basic-crud-functionality-with-the-entity-framework-in-asp-net-mvc-application) that details the CRUD stuff.

Comment: I saw it, but I can't actually understand, how to adapt this to my task.

Comment: If you're having trouble understanding a tutorial, then focus on the areas that are giving you problems and research and read up on those ideas until you do understand

Comment: In the tutorial we create users, but how do I work with users from standart registration in the asp.net?